# SQLite DB Issues

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to do an insert into this database and i'll getting an error. Any ideas on what i'd doing wrong? It's a null exception error when i try and load this fragment.

Helper Class:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                    KEY_CHARTING_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                                    KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE + " INTEGER, " +
                                    KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS  + " INTEGER, " +
                                    KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE + " TEXT, " +
                                    KEY_CHARTING_NOTES + " TEXT, " +
                                    KEY_CHARTING_PROC + ", " +
                                    "PRIMARY KEY (" + KEY_ROWID + ", " + KEY_CHARTING_DATE + ") ); "
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + ";");
        onCreate(db);
    }

public long createEntry(String date, String temperature, String fertile, String notes) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CHARTING_DATE, date);
    cv.put(KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE, temperature);
    cv.put(KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE, fertile);
    cv.put(KEY_CHARTING_NOTES, notes);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}
```

Update button within another class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sqlDate = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.dateselected);
    sqlTemperature = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.tempvalue);
    sqlFertile = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.fertileswitch);
    sqlNotes = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.chartingnote);

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.chartingupdate:

            boolean success = true;

            try{
            String date = sqlDate.getText().toString();
            String temperature = sqlTemperature.getText().toString();
            String fertile = sqlFertile.getText().toString();
            String notes = sqlNotes.getText().toString();

            SQLHelper entry = new SQLHelper(getActivity());

            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(date, temperature, fertile, notes);
            entry.close();
            } catch (Exception e ) {
                success = false;

                String err_msg = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
                d.setTitle("Error Inserting");
                TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                tv.setText(err_msg);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();

            } finally {
                if (success) {
                    Context context = getActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Charting Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Context context = getActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Charting Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            break;
        case R.id.pickdate:
            Context context2 = getActivity();
            Toast.makeText(context2, "Hello toast 2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

```
public SQLHelper open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Error Says:
05-12 19:56:23.218: E/SQLiteLog(791): (1) near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error

The problem is my table create.... The PK is on two column's. One an AUTOINCREMENT and another a date field. It's not liking it for some reason. If i change the PK to only that one AUTOINCREMENT column it works... Guess i'll have to just set it as the date field.

Comment: It would help if you posted your stacktrace

Comment: Is `ourDatabase` properly initialized?

Comment: Pls post your log, so that we can get clear idea about your actual error.

Comment: Post the whole stack trace and consider using `insertOrThrow()` instead for more info.

Comment: Where would i use that?

Comment: What line throws the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare KEY_ROWID to be primary

```
KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the code where you initialize `ourDatabase` but in case you dind't do it properly, it has to be:

```
SQLiteDatabse ourDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
```

Also check with the debugger that all the fields you send to `createEntry` are not null (`date, temperature, fertile, notes`)

Comment: P.S. Why do they all have to be not null? in the database definition it only specifies one as not null.